# Rotating wheel as menu in android with menu items changing every day

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement to create a rotating wheel menu for my android application. I found an example [here](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu) but in this it has to be a set of fixed menu items. In other words, it takes in a wheel image and rotates that.

[image]

I need to create something like the below one in which the menu items keep changing every day. Should be able to change the items(text) on the wheel.

[image]

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 3):

I know it was a long time ago but I'm also looking to find what you have and this is the result with my rating

> https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu - 2 stars
>   https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView - 3 stars
>   https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/Android-CircleMenu - 4.5 stars
>   https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu - 5 stars

The keyword are: "wheel menu", "circle menu"

Hope to help those who come after.